# Working with bit streams

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a base64 encoded bit stream, I want to work with. After decoding it with `base64.b64decode` I get a bytes object (Py3k btw) containing the decoded code. The problem is now, that I would like to work on that bytes object with bit-wise operations, such as shifting, bit wise `and` etc, but that is not possible as it is a bytes sequence.

Is there any way to use binary operations on that decoded code?

Comment: You could convert it to a single (long) integer and then work with that

Comment: @Knio: Please post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using

```
list(bytestring)
```

Eg.

```
>>> bstring=b"Hello World"
>>> list( bstring)
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]
>>>
```

If you want one huge bitfield instead of all those octets

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:(x<<8)+y,list(b"Hello World"))
87521618088882533792115812
>>> bin(_)
'0b100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100'
>>>
```

You didn't say how you are counting the bits, perhaps they are supposed to be reversed

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:(x<<8)+y,list(b"Hello World"[::-1]))
121404708493354166158910792
>>> bits=bin(_)[2:]
```

and pad the string to even bytes

```
>>> bits=bits.zfill(((len(bits)-1)//8+1)*8)
>>> bits
'0110010001101100011100100110111101010111001000000110111101101100011011000110010101001000'
```

turn the first 6 bits into an int

```
>>> int(bits[:6],2)
25
```

and then the following 4 bits

```
>>> int(bits[6:10],2)
1
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to work in between each bytes. For example 6 bits of byte 1, then the remaining 2 bits and the first 2 bits of byte 2 etc.

Comment: Ok, I added how to make a big long bitfield :)

Comment: I had something like this before too, but I did't really like having to go with a string in between, given that I would give a lot resources away by that. I hoped for a more-native approach when working with pure binary data.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make your `bytes` object mutable then you can construct a `bytearray` from it:

```
mutable = bytearray(b"immutable")
```

This will let you modify the individual bytes through normal assignments

```
mutable[0] = mutable[1] = 32
```

If you need to do bit-wise operations then I suggest trying [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) (with apologies for recommending my own module). It works for Python 3 and lets you do bit-wise slicing, shifting, logical operations and much more.

```
>>> s = bitstring.BitArray(bytes=b'your_bytes_object')
>>> s.hex
'0x796f75725f62797465735f6f626a656374'
>>> ten_bits = s[5:15]
>>> print(ten_bits, ten_bits.int)
0b0010110111 183
>>> print(ten_bits << 2)
0b1011011100
>>> print(s[0:6] & '0b110100')
0b010100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.x, you could try using [Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/). It can do very elegant parsing of data, including [bit data](http://construct.wikispaces.com/tut-bitwise).

It hasn't had so much active development recently, so I'm not sure what would be involved in making it work for Python 3.x. But for 2.x it's great.